# Spark SQL: cast a variable from a case when

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How do I change the datatype of variable from a case when statement in spark SQL? I can't find any documentation for this anywhere

For e.g. I would have thought the below would work:

```
SELECT cast(CASE WHEN my_var = 'one'
            THEN null
            ELSE 0
            END AS new_var as Integer)
FROM my_table
```

I get a syntax error when I try this.

I have also tried:

```
SELECT      CASE WHEN my_var = 'one'
            THEN null
            ELSE 0
            END AS cast(new_var as Integer)
FROM my_table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the alias outside of the cast:

```
SELECT cast(CASE WHEN my_var = 'one'
            THEN null
            ELSE 0
            END as int) as new_var
FROM my_table
```